# [TypeError: (0 , react_router_dom_1.useParams) is not a function]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, enzyme

I have a component which uses react-router-dom's `useParams` hook to get params.

It is used in my component as :

/// Child.tsx

```
const Child = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    return <div>Child!</div>
}
```

while writing unit tests, i'm facing the above error while mounting the component.

Things I tried is mocking `useParams` like this :

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({         /// This is at top level after imports
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: () => ({
    id: 'txnabcd',
  }),
}))
```

Unit test:

```
descibe("mounts", ()=>{
      it("mounts the component", ()=>{
         mount(<Child />       /// Failing here 
       })
  })
```

Where could I be possibly wrong?

Comment: I think generally the idea is to not mock what you don't own. Why not render this `Child` component into a wrapper that provides the routing context and route with param?

Comment: Could you show some example that are helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mocking `react-router-dom`'s useParams

// __ mocks __/react-router-dom.js

```
const reactRouter = require('react-router-dom')
const useParams = jest.fn()
module.exports = {
  ...reactRouter,
  useParams,
}
```

Inside test-file standard import and mockReturnvalue for useParams:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
...
useParams.mockReturnValue({ id: 'txnabcd' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking 3rd-party code you might try rendering the `Child` component into a routing context and route with an `id` route param.

Example:

```
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

describe("mounts", () => {
  it("mounts the component", () => {
    mount(
      <Router initialEntries={["/test/1234"]}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/test/:id" element={<Child />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    ); 
  });
});
```